# how can I make a site wide favicon

Tags: favicon

I'd like to make a site wide icon for my website.  Using Corel Photopaint X5, but it doesn't have an .ico export option.

I can make a 1-page-only favicon by exporting a 32x32 pixel .png file and then using the command
    
(my code examples are always trimmed out.)
on each page.  However I've many,many pages, hence the need for a site-wide one.

I've used an on-line converter to make an .ico file 16,32,48 pixels which I've uploaded to my webroot.  Permissions are 755.  However no luck.

For reference my webroot is:  my-domain.com/www/   My server uses this instead of public_html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code in header :

```html
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

Comment: Thanks it works!  I should add that one one-line ico generator generates images in the wrong format.  That was an Apple product and the .ico file didn't display any image while sitting on my pc.  I think I can even try to relocate the favicon.ico to different directories & names?

Comment: It works only for the Home page, which carries the code.  I was hoping I wouldn't have to code it for each page.